# Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm developing a project that uses Celery as a task queue. The project's configuration specifies RabbitMQ as the message broker and result backend, but I want to use Celery without RabbitMQ. When I try to run the Celery worker, it fails with the following error message:

consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 61] Connection refused.

How can I configure Celery to work without RabbitMQ as the message broker and result backend? I've already tried running Celery without RabbitMQ, but without success.

Comment: celery won't start without a message broker, why do you need it?

Comment: just needed to run in prod env

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to run on the localhost5000 and it worked

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:5000'  # for RabbitMQ
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:5000'  # for RabbitMQ
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).